# Using a SELECT CASE statement in ActiveRecord, as Rails model default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, User, which can either be an individual or a company, depending on the value of a boolean, `is_company`. If the user is a company, `company_name` stores the name; if the user is an individual, `first_name` and `last_name` stores their name.

In the vast majority of cases, I want the users to be sorted by `last_name` OR `company_name` by default, so I'm using a default_scope in my User model.

However, the way I have it - even though it works for SQLLite - is not database agnostic. Can anyone let me know how I can refactor this to accept a parameter of "true" in the case statement?

```
default_scope select('users.*')
default_scope select('CASE WHEN is_company = "t" THEN company_name ELSE last_name END AS sort_name')
default_scope order('sort_name ASC')
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should split these two enities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do a modest redesign to handle this at the time you write to the database.

- Create a new column on your User table for `display_name`
- Create a `before_save` callback in your User model that sets the display name like:

  ```
  before_save :set_display_name

  def set_display_name
   self.display_name = self.is_company? ? self.company_name : self.last_name 
  end
  ```
- Change your default_scope to just order by the new column

Comment: Yep - that's what I'll do - will make life so much easier!

Answer (score 2):

You need to rethink your design. A user that can be a company doesn't sound like good design to me. I think you're better off with separate `User` and `Company` models.

Your sorting will be much easier that way too..

Comment: sorry for spoiling such a great reputation number ;)

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to reach 1000 :)

Comment: The issue is that everything a company can do, a user can do with very few exceptions. The only difference is the first/last name issue

Comment: That is beside the point. A user is not a company. Users work at a company. A company has employees (users). Create your models as they are in the real world.